# How to force the phone to connect to the internet?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, settings, data-connection, internet

I own Xperia Mini Pro which has Android 2.1-update1. I am facing an issue on Internet Connection. I downloaded the settings for my Edge Connection from my SIM services. Sometimes after downloading the settings it instantly connects to the Internet. But sometimes it doesn't. I can see the APNs on Access Point Names section. Also that APN is selected. But still its not connecting to the Internet. I cannot see Edge connection notification on the Notification Bar.

I want to force the phone to connect to the internet, Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Can you be more specific around when it does have EDGE connection and when it doesn't. Does it depend on where you are or does it appear and disappear even if you stay in one place?

Comment: @Dmitry: There is nothing Special about Edge Connection. Its very similar to GPRS.

Comment: @Xperia That was not my question. I am asking if you problem occurs when you stay in one place or only when you are on the move (i.e. it works at home, doesn't around the corner from your home)

Comment: @Dmitry: Sorry for my wrong understanding. Its happening on both cases.

Comment: @XperiaMiniPro Thanks. Have you double checked the APN settings with your carrier (e.g. on their website) to make sure that what got downloaded to the phone is correct? I've seen a few times when downloaded settings were out of date/incorrect

Comment: @Dmitry: I am 100% sure that those settings are correct. And they are valid. I was using the same settings for more than 6 months. All of sudden now its giving problem. I have got enough balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a way to connect to internet on my Xperia Mini Pro android mobile.

Go to 
     Settings ==> Wireless & network settings ==> Mobile networks ==> Network Mode
Its going to open another window with title as Preferred network mode.

Now try to Select WCDMA only option. Wait for 10 sec. We can see the network is getting reset and try to find the 3G signal. 
Now open the same pop up again and select GSM(Edge or 2G) connection. Now again networking related stuff gets reset again.

This is how I force my mobile to connect to internet.